# Exchange admin center - message trace - delivered, delivered then failed

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I was investigating something else when I've noticed this behavior: for a non-existing mailbox, Office365 "message trace" shows "delivered" two times then "failed" status.

Is this a normal thing? I was expecting just one "failed" status.

I've tested with a non-existing mailbox, same result all 3 times, see print below.

Result 1: Office 365 successfully sent the message to the following external address "..."

Result 2: Office 365 successfully sent the message to the following external address "..."

Result 3: Office 365 received the message that you specified, but couldn't deliver it to the recipient (‎...) due to the following error: ‎554 5.4.14 Hop count exceeded - possible mail loop ATTR34 [.....prod.outlook.com 2023-11-26T00:56:12.336Z ...]‎

At "Mail flow" and "Accepted domains", both domains ("real" and "onmicrosoft.com") are "Authoritative".

[image: Exchange admin center - message trace results]

Answer (score 0):

Does "for a non-existing mailbox" mean a mailbox that doesn't exist in the authoritative domain, or is it completely fictitious?

Does your organization have an on-premises Exchange server? Is there a three-party connector?
Does this problem occur only to one user? Can he send messages to other external users with the same domain?
This is a blog on this issue, you can check out more suggestions：[Fix NDR error 5.4.6 or 5.4.14 in Exchange Online - Exchange | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/ndr/fix-error-code-5-4-6-through-5-4-20-in-exchange-online#im-an-email-admin-how-do-i-fix-this-issue)